# How to query over list of tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

This returns a list of all tables in the dataset:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM data.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name not like '%INFORMATION%'
```

These tables all have a `date_of_data` field.

How can one iterate `SELECT max(date_of_data) FROM <table_name>` over all tables returned above?

I've tried using wildcards with:

```
SELECT max(date_of_data) FROM `data.*`
```

but this only returns a single value for the most up-to-date table instead of the max(date_of_data) for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried using wildcards with:
>      `SELECT max(date_of_data) FROM data.*`
>   but this only returns a single value for the most up-to-date table **instead of the max(date_of_data) for each table**.

```
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table_name, MAX(date_of_data) AS max_date
FROM `data.*`
GROUP BY table_name
```

Comment: Hero!  Missing the closing backtick on `data.* but then it works.